# Yaml syntax error on Github Action regex input

Tags: github-actions, checkmarx

I'm always having a message on our GitHub Action that says I'm getting an incorrect syntax from the line of **zip-include**:

> You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 17

```yaml
name: Poging Gwapo Scan
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "feature/pogi/**"
      - "release/gwapo/**"


jobs:
  scan:
    uses: pogi/pogi-actions/.github/workflows/checkmarx.yml@v1
    with:
      checkmarx-team: POGI/gwapo
      exclude-files: "pogi/gwapo/index.php,pogi/index.php"
      zip-exclude: "/.github\/.*,files\/pogi\/.*"
    secrets:
      checkmarx-username: ${{ secrets.POGI_CHECKMARX_USERNAME }}
      checkmarx-password: ${{ secrets.POGI_CHECKMARX_PASSWORD }}
```

Comment: Please add the error message from Github

Comment: error message is "You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 17"

Comment: So your problem is a YAML problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this **string literal**:

```
"/.github\/.*,files\/pogi\/.*"
```

You want your string to be considered as a **regex**, but for now, it is just a string input.

As a string, when you use the `\` character, the string expects not permitted characters such as `"`, but the `/` character is OK and does not need to be escaped.

Since the `\` is a special character in a string, because it is used for escaping, you have to escape it itself:

```
"/.github\\/.*,files\\/pogi\\/.*"
```

And that's it.